# what ebay api can I use for getting specific buyer feedback?

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using [GetFeedback api in ebay](https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetFeedback.html#Request.FeedbackID), But their using feedback id.

If i use the sample example in this api request,returned feedback summary only.

How can I get the feedback details?

What is feedback id? How can I get this feedback id?

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eBay is allowing to get Feedback based on **UserID, Item ID, Transaction ID, or OrderLineItemID** attributes.

**UserID** : You can get UserID via **GetOrders** API. (Attribute name is **BuyerUserID** in GetOrders API)

**Item ID** : You can get Item ID when product is export via **AddItem/AddItems/AddFixedPriceItem/GetSellerList** API.

**Transaction ID** : You can get Transaction ID via **GetOrders** API.

Your order name syntax is **transaction_id-itemid**.You can split from Order name it self.

**OrderLineItemID** You can get OrderLineItemID via **GetOrders**. (Attribute name is **OrderLineItemID** in GetOrders API)

You should pass any attribute value from above four attributes, eBay will give you Feedback based on attribute request.

API is not require  **FeedbackID** in the request.

Ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetFeedbackRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
  <UserID>magicalbookseller</UserID>
</GetFeedbackRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the the request parameter `Request.DetailLevel` to `ReturnAll`

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetFeedback.html#Request.DetailLevel

In the response, you can retrieve the comment in the below node:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetFeedback.html#Response.FeedbackDetailArray.FeedbackDetail.CommentText